# Flutter: VSCode shortcut to have the list of @override

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

Using VSCode, is there a shortcut (or any other way) to get the list of all Flutter @override methods?

Comment: I don't know VSCode but DartAnalyzer used by VSCode provides something. In IntelliJ it's available in the context-menu of the class under generate. There is also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32677 from the maintainer of the VSCode Dart plugin

Comment: OK. Thank you.  I will wait for this fix, then.

Comment: Might not be the correct solution but a workaround. You can do **Ctrl + Mouse left click** to open that class, there you can see all the function that you can override. I simply do copy paste of that function and change the function body.

Answer (score 8):

Although seeing a full list isn't implemented yet (as [seen in the issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32677) linked in the comments), the overridable methods to appear in the completion list as long as you've typed something; even if it's only a single character. You can use `Ctrl`+`Space` to force the completion list to open if required.

Answer (score 6):

If you know the the first letter of the method you want to override, simply type that letter, and vs code will immediately offer a list of all methods of the super class that begins with that letter.
Upon choosing, it will complete the method - with annotation and comment, nicely.
For example, in a Superclass I have a method with a signature of

```
Future<void> init() async {}
```

and in the subclass editor, I merely type an "i", vs code pops up the init() amongst others, and upon choosing it writes the following:

```
  @override
  Future<void> init() {
    // TODO: implement init
    return super.init();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Place the cursor to the red squiggly underlined keyword. You can then press `ctrl+.` in vscode & insert the `override` methods for windows.

[image]

Just click on the option that shows "Create 1 missing override" or maybe the override lists.

Answer (score 1):

I am using version 1.49 (latest)
In the class name you want to implement, <Ctrl+.> When you press,'create n missing override(s)' appears.

[image]

Comment: ok but how to override a method that is not missing, since it is not mandatory to override it?

Answer (score 1):

On mac, if you do "option(alt) + ." you will get a list of the overridable methods.

If it doesn't work, try "option(alt) + ;"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just type the keyword "**overide**" and press **Space**. VSCode will show you the list of overide methods.

[image]